# this.<variable> is undefined in method

Tags: angular, typescript, this, observable

I can not access a class variable in a class method.

This is my class:

```
[imports, decorator......]
export class CardboardComponent implements OnInit {
  operations: Operation[];
  workplaces: Workplace[];
  workplaceGroups: WorkplaceGroup[];
  rowLeadItems: String[];

  constructor(private cardboardService: CardboardService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
    this.createRowLeadItems();
  }

  getData() {
    console.log('Data started');
    console.log(this);
    this.cardboardService.getOperations()
      .subscribe(operations => {
        if (operations != undefined) {
          this.operations = operations;
        }
      });
    console.log('Data finished');
  }

  createRowLeadItems() {
    console.log('Row Lead started');
    console.log(this);
    console.log('Operations: ' + this.operations);
    console.log('Row Lead finished');
  }

}
```

The console output looks like:
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtyLS.png)

I have no idea why this.operations is undefined at generateRowLeadItems(), when "this" is working fine and I can see it in the console.

Comment: It is because `getOperations` (and anything you subscribe to) is an async operation. Think of it like `setTimeout`

Comment: your `getData` is behaving async thats why its undefined

Comment: also ngOnInit calls the function async?

Comment: no it doesnt, `getData` is calling `getOperations` method which should be `http` call i guess thats why this function is async

Comment: you need to call your `createRowLeadItems()` inside subscription of getOperations method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually your `getdata` is a async so it will take some to get data from your service on that time `createRowLeadItems()` will get executed before `getdata()` completes. it better to call the `createRowLeadItems()` function inside `getdata()`

remove calling `createRowLeadItems()` inside the `ngOnInit()` and then call inside the `getdata()`

```
getData() {
  console.log('Data started');
  console.log(this);
  this.cardboardService.getOperations()
    .subscribe(operations => {
      if (operations != undefined) {
        this.operations = operations;
        createRowLeadItems(); <-------- calling here
      }
    });
  console.log('Data finished');
}
```